# Removing Duplicate Jquery Script Call breaks the Responsive Menu

Tags: jquery, duplicates, break

so I'm probably just being a total dufus here but hoping someone can help! I have a webpage here:

http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/?post_type=tribe_events

If you type something into the search part at the top of the events section and hit 'Find Events' you'll notice it doesn't work. The reason is because there are two jquery script calls (due to the fact that I've embedded wordpress into my site with a customised header & footer as part of a child theme and the custom header contains a second jquery script call for the responsive mobile menu).

So I can remove the call to jquery that I have in my header (don't know how to remove the one generated by the events calendar plugin), the one that looks like this on line 104:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but when I do so it breaks the responsive mobile menu (rmm). I would have thought that the wordpress plugins jquery call (lines 37-49) would've kept the rmm working but apparently not? These are the script calls from the plugin on lines 37-29.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js?ver=2.0.7'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js?ver=3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/jquery-resize/jquery.ba-resize.min.js?ver=1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/resources/tribe-events.min.js?ver=3.8.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/resources/tribe-events-bar.min.js?ver=3.8.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.sopd.org.uk/events/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I fixed it by adding this to functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_more_jquery');
function no_more_jquery(){
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . 
($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . 
"://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js", false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

And removing the jquery call that was in my custom header. Basically, it seems like both applications are happy to run off this version of jquery (but wern't happy to run off each others) so this just replaces the plugins jquery script call with one they can share.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help anyone else, an easier solution is to replace the jquery script that is in your header with the jquery script that both applications can share